# JS Return array based on the comparison of two arrays with nested elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, filter

Using Angular and trying to return result based on the comparison of two arrays. Here is what I have:

```
$scope.fbFriends = [{"id":1234,"name":'bob'},
                    {"id":4567,"name":'john'}, 
                    {"id":8910,"name":'totoro'}];
$scope.appFriends = [{"id":1,"name":'bob',"fb_id":1234},          
                     {"id":2,"name":'john',"fb_id":4567}];
```

I would like to filter the friends that exist in both and return only the ones from fbFriends that don't exist in appFriends.
This is what I did but it doesn't work it returns way too many times the same.

```
$scope.not_friends = [];
        $scope.filtered = [];
        for (var i=0; i < $scope.fbFriends.length; i++) {
           for (var j=0; j < $scope.appFriends.length; j++) {
             if ($scope.fbFriends[i].id !== $scope.appFriends[j].fb_id) {
               $scope.not_friends = $scope.fbFriends[i];
               $scope.filtered.push($scope.not_friends);
             }
           }
        };
        console.log($scope.filtered);
```

What is wrong in this approach? 
Bonus, could I integrate that in a filter and use it in a ng-repeat of fbFriends ?

Thanks!!

Comment: For starters `$scope.not_friends = $scope.fbFriends[i];`: I assume you want to `push` the item here?

Comment: you should first extract an object of primitives you need to compare, likely on `fb_id`. that way, you don't have to loop a loop (n^2), you can do it in more like (n*2)

Comment: Yes in the end I will return only the ones that are in both in the view. Getting the list of fb ids to compare is good but then I need to extract from the array only the ones that didn't match. Doesn't that make more code?

Comment: @commandantp Is the `not_friends` suppose to use in view only or you just need to display `not_friends`?

Comment: @alberto Not_friends was just here to help, in the end I will update the fbFriends array and display it in the view. At first I thought I could use a filter in the view directly

Comment: @commandantp Can you provide the html codes?

Comment: @alberto it is a simple <div ng-repeat="fbFriend in fbFriends"> fbFriend.name </div>

Comment: @commandantp So, the main goal is to display the `fbFriend.name` that is present in the `appFriends`?

Comment: @alberto The contrary, display those who are not there :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `if block`: you have to check for equality and then - since you are searching for friends that are NOT contained in the fbFriends - remove the object.

I've rewritten your code and it seems to work properly.

```
$scope.fbFriends = [{"id":1234,"name":'bob'},
        {"id":4567,"name":'john'},
        {"id":8910,"name":'totoro'}];
      $scope.appFriends = [{"id":1,"name":'bob',"fb_id":1234},
        {"id":2,"name":'john',"fb_id":4567}];

      for (var i=0; i < $scope.appFriends.length; i++) {
        // we parse the 'reference array'
        for (var j=0; j < $scope.fbFriends.length; j++) {
          // we check every value inside the 'container array'
          if ($scope.fbFriends[j].id == $scope.appFriends[i].fb_id) {

            // the element is alredy inside the appFriends

            $scope.fbFriends.splice(j,1);
          }
        }
      }

      console.log($scope.fbFriends);
```

For further reference see an algorithm book (Mine suggestion is [Introduction to Algorithms](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms) by Thomas H. Cormen, but anyone will do.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic set difference operation

```
difference = function(a, b, eq) {
  return a.filter(function(x) {
    return b.every(function(y) {
      return !eq(x, y)
    });
  });
}
```

where `a, b` are arrays and `eq` - an equality function.

And this is how to apply it to your problem:

```js
fbFriends = [{"id":1234,"name":'bob'},
                    {"id":4567,"name":'john'}, 
                    {"id":8910,"name":'totoro'}];
appFriends = [{"id":1,"name":'bob',"fb_id":1234},          
                     {"id":2,"name":'john',"fb_id":4567}];


difference = function(a, b, eq) {
  return a.filter(function(x) {
    return b.every(function(y) {
      return !eq(x, y)
    });
  });
}

onlyFb = difference(fbFriends, appFriends, function(f, a) {
  return f.id === a.fb_id
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(onlyFb))
```

Comment: this looks really good! Let me try to implement it ! Do you think I could take the difference function out of my controller and create a filter out of it?